# Parametrized URL to set dashboard filters for Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

We want to pass some Parameters from our UI to Cognos Dashboard (IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1 R7 (LTS)) via url method. Is it possible for Dashboard to set filters dynamically from url or with SDK ?
We are planning to embed the Dashboard URL within iFrame interface and want to pass values from custom UI.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dSub.png